# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath method not firing

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xib

I placed a TableView on my xib file with the following method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    NSLog(@"FIRED THE EVENT");

}
```

and it doesn't seem to be firing when I click on a cell in the table. Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to include `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate` in your .h file

Comment: Yes did both. This is not it.

Comment: Assuming you this is in the same class as connected to your "Hide a UIView" question, then I would have to say something is wrong with how your nib file is created. Is the nib referring to the correct class? You probably want to go over the nib setup with a fine tooth comb to make sure something wasn't missed.

Comment: Is the `UITableView`'s `delegate` connected to `File's Owner`? Same for the `datSource`.